# Object initialized in "init" cannot be accessed in "viewDidLoad"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, initialization

I have a strange issue: I load object data in "init" method. When I try to access it in the "viewDidLoad" my app crashes. Here is the code:

```
@interface UploadCenterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *videos;
}

@end

@implementation UploadCenterViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];  
    if (self) {
        if (![self loadVideos]) {
            [self saveVideos];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)saveVideos {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:videos];
    [defaults setObject:encodedData forKey:@"VIDEOS"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(bool)loadVideos {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedData = [defaults objectForKey:@"VIDEOS"];
    if (encodedData) {
        videos = (NSMutableArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedData];

        NSLog(@"array size: %d", [videos count]);

        return true;
    } else {
        videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        return false;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%d", [videos count]);
}
```

When loading the data, the "videos" array contains an object. When accessing it in the "viewDidLoad" the entire app crashes.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Looks a memory management related issue. Use @property for `videos` and use it as `self.videos` instead of `videos`. That will fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `videos` as an `@property` and use it as `self.videos` everywhere. The crash is due to the fact that `videos` is getting released once you assign a value to it. The scope of `videos` is only inside that method and it can crash due to this. Since you want to use this outside that method, you need to retain it and you can use @property for this as mentioned below.

for eg:-

```
@interface UploadCenterViewController () {}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *videos;

@end

-(void)saveVideos {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.videos];
    [defaults setObject:encodedData forKey:@"VIDEOS"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(bool)loadVideos {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedData = [defaults objectForKey:@"VIDEOS"];
    if (encodedData) {
        self.videos = (NSMutableArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedData];
        NSLog(@"array size: %d", [self.videos count]);
        return true;
    } else {
        self.videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        return false;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%d", [self.videos count]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to retain the result of `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedData]`.

Read the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).